# FTP Server: Single user, multiple roots

Tags: ftp

I'm working for a company where we have lot of different projects. Now we have an FTP Server, where every user can login using their active directory credentials. Project owners of the company we do the project for also have access using AD.

Every user has access to the FTP Server, however employees can be in multiple projects, but should be jailed to each of them.

A user can for ex. have:

/Project1
/Project2
/Home

But a project owner should only see his own project

/Project1

Any way to achieve this behavior using for ex. ProFTPd? DefaultRoot ~ works well for jailing, but only one directory...

Answer (score 0):

I have used [CrushFTP](http://www.crushftp.com) for this.  It is simple to configure and has a wide range of features beyond that.  Support is excellent even with the trial version and price is reasonable.